# Could you help me identify this rhythm by name?

Tags: rhythm

[image]

I know how people refer to this rhythm in a language other than English, but I couldn't find a translation, which makes it difficult to search for it.

Comment: How is it called in the non-English language? Perhaps that helps people answering.

Comment: Not only am I not aware of a name for this, I cannot imagine any great need to name this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above you have eighth-note triplets, and below you have quarter-note triplets. It's largely as simple as that.

Keep in mind that a triplet is three notes within the time span of only two of those notes. So you can have all kinds of triplets based on all kinds of note values. Similar logic applies to tuplets more generally.

Occasionally I've heard quarter-note triplets referred to as "box triplets," but that's the most specific I've ever heard.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the [hemiola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemiola#Rhythm) rhythm. IME hemiola is more often found in pieces in 3/4, where accents on the 1 and 3 of one bar, and the 2 of the next bar, give a momentary feel of a 3/2 bar -- still three-time, but with the beats being twice as long. Now if you changed the notation, and wrote triplet quavers/8ths instead of crotchets/quarters, then the regular pulse would be your top line, and the hemiola would be your bottom line.